# Deserialization problem with Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, dictionary

when i am trying to serialize a dictionary, everything worked fine. but when i am deserializing it is showing count as 0. But, it works fine with a list. What is goingon exactly when we are deserializing a list and a dictionary?

Comment: Which serializer? It matters a **lot**? Is this `XmlSerializer`? `BinaryFormatter`? `DataContractSerializer`? `NetDataContractSerializer`? JSON? proto bufs? SOAP? I'm afraid each has subtly different behaviour. Many (not all) *do* support dictionary serialization. You also may need additional steps if you've done custom serialization (`ISerializable` etc).

Comment: i am trying to serialize using BinaryFormatter..

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries don't really support serialization. This is a known issue which troubles many programmers, so if you Google ".NET Dictionary Serialization" you'll get many results with "how-to"s and workarounds.

This [blog post](http://www.myboogpages.com/2006/12/net-dictionary-serialization-problem.html), for example, suggests you use the KeyedCollection class instead.

Comment: You're correct about dictionaries, but exceptions CAN be serialized.

Comment: @Timores, I've erased the part about exceptions.
I had trouble serializing exceptions due to a contained Dictionary member, but that may be related to a specific type of exception i was serializing, or to the fact i was using the XmlSerializer, or maybe even to the fact I was using VB. In any way, I don't think you can generally say that all exceptions are serializable, I suspect the truth is somewhere in between. Please elaborate if you have additional info on this subject.

Comment: In general, not all classes are serializable, I agree. And we have to define whether we are talking about binary serialization or XML serialization. I was thinking of the former, where you can implement ISerializable in order to take over the serialization process and serialize a class with an embedded dictionary.
You can use any .NET language, by the way, they are all semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you use .Net 3.5 you can use the DataContractSerializer which will serialize a dictionary. It's also faster than a BinaryFormatter or XmlSerializer.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("a","a");

DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(dict.GetType());
MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
dcs.WriteObject(byteStream, dict);
byteStream.Position = 0;

var dict2 = dcs.ReadObject(byteStream);
```